# python - urls.py regex help with coordinates

Tags: python, regex, gps, coordinates, django-urls

I tried searching but could not find an answer for this.

I am trying to write a function that takes in coordinates, ie latitude and longitude. For example, `53.345633,-6.267014`.

These will then be fed into the Google Maps API as the users current location, and directions to some nearby places (I already have these locations stored somewhere) and the directions will hopefully be returned.

So, I pretty much have all the Maps work done, but I can't test it because, frustratingly enough, I simply cannot figure out the regex for inside `urls.py`.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm hoping its simple enough for you guys. I tried it earlier but failed miserably! It's so frustrating coz I'm so close to finishing this part too!!

Thanks for the help!

PS Is the format for coordinates advisable, with the comma? Perhaps `53.345633+-6.267014` would be better (then I can just use `my_coords = coords.replace("+", ", ")` or something)??

Comment: Can you please clarify? I'm assuming based on the fact that you reference "urls.py" you are actually making a Django-based webapp, or is your python script called urls.py and you're using some sort of regex to do some sort of syntax checking, or is something else going on? Your question needs to be reworded before I (an probably anyone else looking at this) understands what you're trying to ask.

Comment: Yes, just to follow up on this, it is Django based. The regex I was using was for inside `urls.py` to ensure I was getting GPS Coordinates in the URL. I got an answer below and slightly modified it to get my answer. Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure I get it but you can try something like :

```
def str2cords(scords):
    return [float(c) for c in scords.split(',')] #or maybe just scords.split(',') since float might mess up the exact cords?
```

or regex :

```
'/(-?\d+\.\d+),(-?\d+\.\d+)/'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have it working now. Yours is very similar to mine: `(r'^coords/(\-?\d{1,2}\.\d+?\+\-?\d{1,2}\.\d+)$','foo.bar.nearestcoords'),` Thanks!!

Comment: Glad I helped, keep in mind you don't need to escape the `-`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the dot to be optional.

```
(?P<lon>-?\d+.?\d+)/(?P<lat>-?\d+.?\d+)
```